# app.config are not saving the values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, app-config

My `App.Config` is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <appSettings>
  <add key="foo" value=""/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I try to save the `foo` value using the following method:

```
private void SaveValue(string value) {
    var config =
        ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("foo", value);
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified); 
}
```

but this not change the value of it. and I don't get a exception.
 how to fix this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Here is the complete example [ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration Method (ConfigurationUserLevel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265.aspx)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you are debugging with Visual Studio probably the `<yourexe>.vshost.exe.config` is modified instead of the `<yourexe>.exe.config`. When you build the application in Release mode only the `<yourexe>.exe.config` exists and will be updated.

Your code will also add an extra node to the configuration file. Use something like the code below to update the setting:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["foo"].Value = "text";     
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Answer (score 4):

App.config is copied to the output folder on build, named `<yourexe>.exe.config`. This is the actual configuration file that is loaded and saved on runtime.

Have a look in your output folder, there you will likely find that the configuration file contains your changes.

Comment: is exactly there that I'm seeing. there no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try by first deleting the old value and then add it again

```
 config.AppSettings.Settings.Remove("foo");
 config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("foo", value);
 config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```